# "Word has stopped working" when exiting ProtectedViewWindowBeforeEdit() with Cancel=True

Tags: vba, ms-word, crash, office-2016

We are running W10 x64 LTSB with Office 2016 x86 and Word 16.0.4405.1000.

We are using a custom message box so that the user gets an "OK / Cancel" dialogue when clicking on "Enable Editing" in a document that was opened in Protected view. The code is similar to what you can see here in MSDN:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh128817(v=office.14).aspx

If the user chooses Cancel we pass "True" to the Cancel arguement within the VBA Sub "ProtectedViewWindowBeforeEdit(ByVal PvWindow As ProtectedViewWindow, Cancel As Boolean)".

This results in a warning "Word was unable to read this document." which is fine.

After confirming the warning dialogue Word crashes with "Word has stopped working".

The Eventviewer is logging: #1000 (Application error). Faulting module: mso30win32client.dll

However we are using the same code in Excel 2016 (same version) and it is working fine.

I read that there have been problems with DisplayLink drivers that have caused this issue in the past. We tried disabling hardware accelleration and also switching off COM-add-ins but with no success.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Update:
How to reproduce:

1. Create a DOTM file with Word 2016.
2. In VBA create a module and paste this code:

   ```
   Public appObject As New clsEvents

   Public Sub autoexec()
       Set appObject.WDApp = Word.Application
   End Sub
   ```
3. Create a class module, name it clsEvents and paste this code:

   ```
   Public WithEvents WDApp As Word.Application

   Private Sub WDApp_ProtectedViewWindowBeforeEdit(ByVal PvWindow As ProtectedViewWindow, Cancel As Boolean)
       Cancel = (MsgBox("Text", vbOKCancel, "Event") = vbCancel)
   End Sub
   ```
4. Place the DOTM file into the Word startup location (see Word Options --> Advanced --> File locations --> Startup).
5. Open a file in protected view (Word --> File --> Open --> Browse --> Select a file --> expand Open dropdown --> Open in protected view)
6. Click "Enable editing" in the ProtectedView bar.
7. Press "Cancel" in the MsgBox dialogue and confirm the following error message with OK.
8. "Microsoft Word has stopped working"

Comment: Can you create a [minimal, complete and verifiable sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with instructions to repro?